# Project position on Earth to higher altitude with local azimuth and elevation

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinate

I have a position on Earth (1,1,) of which I want to project a straight line with a known azimuth and elevation to a certain altitude, . Thus obtaining new coordinates on the projected sphere, (2,2,+).

How do I calculate 2 and 2 with all other information available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altitude change does not influence on azimuth (as projection of path onto sphere), so you can use `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point` section [from here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to get final coordinates from start coordinates and bearing:

```
Formula:    
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
  where φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), 
  δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius

JavaScript:    (all angles     in radians)
var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));

The longitude can be normalised to −180…+180 using (lon+540)%360-180
```